# Wallet style with multiple cells border Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, border, cell

How do I make only the last cell with round corner and black border color? and the rest of the cell will only have left and right border?

This is the design of the cell. The pink part is the section header, the white part is the cell. In the image I have 6 cells and I want the 6th one to have round corner and black border. Cell 1-5 will only have left and right border.

My tableview will contain few sets of todo please see the image under.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         .    
         .
         .

    cell.view.clipsToBounds = true

    if indexPath.row == todoList.count - 1 {
        cell.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        cell.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor   //not working it makes all cell has border
        cell.view.layer.borderWidth = 1
       
    } else {
        //only want left and right with black border
    }
        .    
        .
        .
}
```

Comment: why not to give corner radius and black border to tableView rather than cells?

Comment: It is for tableviewcell not tableview, and I have two tableviewcell for custom header and cell.

Comment: i am asking to give corner radius to tableView

Comment: It is not going to work. The cells are inside the tableview and has padding. How is that going to apply to each set of the sections and cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think @Jithin answer using adding a subview is the easiest and greatest answer, but if you really want to draw your own border line, we can use UIBezierPath to achieve this. (which I think is a little bit overkill for this).

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10.0
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2
    
        // deduct the line width to keep the line stay side the view
        let point1 = CGPoint(x: 0.0 + lineWidth / 2, y: view.frame.height)
        let point2 = CGPoint(x: 0.0 + lineWidth / 2, y: 0.0 + cornerRadius + lineWidth / 2)
        let point3 = CGPoint(x: 0.0 + cornerRadius + lineWidth / 2, y: 0.0 + lineWidth / 2)
        let point4 = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width - cornerRadius - lineWidth / 2, y: 0.0 + lineWidth / 2)
        let point5 = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width - lineWidth / 2, y: 0.0 + cornerRadius + lineWidth / 2)
        let point6 = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width - lineWidth / 2, y: view.frame.height - lineWidth / 2)
    
        // draw the whole line with upper corner radius
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: point1)
        path.addLine(to: point2)
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: point3.x, y: point2.y),
                    radius: cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: .pi,
                    endAngle: -.pi/2,
                    clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: point4)
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: point4.x, y: point5.y),
                    radius: cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: -.pi/2,
                    endAngle: 0,
                    clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: point6)
        path.addLine(to: point1)
    
        let topBorder = CAShapeLayer()
        topBorder.path = path.cgPath
        topBorder.lineWidth = lineWidth
        topBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        topBorder.fillColor = nil

        // add the line to header view
        view.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testingCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    
        cell.cellLabel.text = "\(mockData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])"
        cell.backgroundColor = .green

        if indexPath.row == mockData[indexPath.section].count - 1 {
            cell.setAsLastCell()
            // we can add a mask to cut those area outside our border line
            let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
            let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
            cell.layer.mask = maskLayer
        } else {
            cell.setAsNormalCell()
            cell.layer.mask = nil
        }
    
        return cell
    }
}
```

And here is the UITableViewwCell:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!

    let leftBorder = CALayer()
    let rightBorder = CALayer()
    let bottomBorder = CAShapeLayer()
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10
    let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        leftBorder.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: lineWidth, height: self.frame.height)
        leftBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(leftBorder)

        rightBorder.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - lineWidth, y: 0.0, width: lineWidth, height: self.frame.height)
        rightBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(rightBorder)
    
        // same idea as drawing line in the header view
        let point1 = CGPoint(x: 0.0 + lineWidth / 2, y: 0.0)
        let point2 = CGPoint(x: 0.0 + lineWidth / 2, y: self.frame.height - cornerRadius - lineWidth / 2)
        let point3 = CGPoint(x: cornerRadius + lineWidth / 2, y: self.frame.height - lineWidth / 2)
        let point4 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - cornerRadius - lineWidth / 2, y: self.frame.height - lineWidth / 2)
        let point5 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - lineWidth / 2, y: self.frame.height - cornerRadius - lineWidth / 2)
        let point6 = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width - lineWidth / 2, y: 0.0)
    
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: point1)
        path.addLine(to: point2)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: point3.x, y: point2.y),
                    radius: cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: .pi,
                    endAngle: .pi/2,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: point4)
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: point4.x,y: point5.y),
                    radius: cornerRadius,
                    startAngle: .pi/2,
                    endAngle: 0,
                    clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: point6)
    
        bottomBorder.path = path.cgPath
        bottomBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        bottomBorder.lineWidth = lineWidth
        bottomBorder.fillColor = nil
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
    }

    func setAsNormalCell() {
        leftBorder.isHidden = false
        rightBorder.isHidden = false
        bottomBorder.isHidden = true
    }

    func setAsLastCell() {
        leftBorder.isHidden = true
        rightBorder.isHidden = true
        bottomBorder.isHidden = false
    }

}
```

And of course, the above code is just for testing purposes and maybe a bit messy, but I hope it can explain a bit about drawing a line.

The result:
[image]

Comment: I like both answers but yours is more flexible that if the background is clear I can use it as well. Thanks!

Comment: this will create multiple layer in the when table view will reuse cell. I don't think it is good solution

Comment: @SultanAli Thank you and, Yes you are right, I was just giving a quick answer focusing on drawing the borderline by UIBezierPath, and as I said it was just for testing purposes. When we scroll the tableView and willDisplayHeaderView will get called multiple times, and the same subLayer is added to view multiple times. Even though CALayer is lightweight, this is just not an ideal way to add it. Of cause, we could do something simple like remove all subLayers before adding the new one, but that's not what I want to focus on in the answer.

Comment: So far what I prefer is to create a subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView, override layoutSubviews and add the subLayers there (Interestingly I found that even layoutSubviews get called hence the subLayers is added multiple time, the total number of subLayers will not increase when adding the same subLayers, but that's another story). I will try to update my answer to make it perfect, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @paky thanks for reply, as far my understanding it will increase the number of sublayers in the view if it is a cell or subview of cell

Answer (score 2):

@PpppppPppppp, I managed to get the result with some hacks. Do post if you found another way to do it. Here's the final result:

[image]

Instead of setting left and right borders for cell, set black colour to cell's `contentView` and place a view inside with leading and trailing constraints to make it look like it has a border.

Then provide a `viewForHeaderInSection` and a `viewForFooterInSection` with masked corners as required in your UI. Some hacks required in the footer to hide the top border.

I didn't use any custom `UITableViewCell` or `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` since this is only for demo. FInd the whole code for table view below.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "index: \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 70))
        header.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let innderView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 20, width: header.bounds.width, height: 50))
        header.addSubview(innderView)

        innderView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        innderView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        innderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        innderView.layer.borderWidth = 2
        innderView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        return header
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footer = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 20))
        let innerView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 2, y: 0, width: footer.bounds.width-4, height: footer.bounds.height-2))
        footer.addSubview(innerView)

        innerView.backgroundColor = .white
        innerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        innerView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        
        footer.backgroundColor = .black
        footer.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        footer.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
        return footer
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering it!!

Comment: Sorry, it did helps but doesn't work with the clear background so I picked the other person's answer. I gave you an upvote since it is still very useful!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can give corner radius to your tableview.

```
tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor   
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a UICollectionView extension however it should work the same for UITableView

```
  @objc func addBorder(fromIndexPath:IndexPath, toIndexPath:IndexPath, borderColor:CGColor, borderWidth:CGFloat){
        
    let fromAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: fromIndexPath)!
    let toAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForItem(at: toIndexPath)!
 
    let borderFrame = CGRect(x: fromAttributes.frame.origin.x
                             ,y: fromAttributes.frame.origin.y
                             ,width: fromAttributes.frame.size.width
                             ,height: toAttributes.frame.origin.y + toAttributes.frame.size.height - fromAttributes.frame.origin.y)
    
    let borderTag = ("\(fromIndexPath.row)\(fromIndexPath.section)\(toIndexPath.row)\(toIndexPath.section)" as NSString).integerValue
    
    if let borderView = self.viewWithTag(borderTag){
        borderView.frame = borderFrame
    }
    else{
        let borderView = UIView(frame: borderFrame)
        borderView.tag = borderTag
        borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        borderView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        borderView.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        borderView.layer.borderColor =  borderColor
        
        self.addSubview(borderView)
    }
}
```